# How well are the covid-19 vaccines doing in the field?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

By now, millions of people have been given the Pfizer and Moderna vaccines in the US, and the same is true for those and other vaccines in many other countries. I have not found in the media any news about infection rates in that group, and I think that would be interesting to know. I would be particularly interested to know whether there have been any hospitalizations among the vaccinated population. On the one hand, I would expect it to make the news if a vaccinated person ended up hospitalized with the disease, but 22 million Americans have been vaccinated (at least the first dose), and surely more than ten million got vaccinated  more than a week ago. Have there really been no hospitalizations in that group? If so, that would be great news.

Comment: There have been news reports of severe covid *shortly after* receiving the vaccine, but this is to be expected as it is known that it takes some time for vaccines to confer any immunity. The problem is that with no systematic following of people who have been vaccinated and no control group, it is not nearly as easy to report the statistics you are asking for as it may seem. Presumably there are postmarket trials occurring and if I find anything on those I'll consider making that an answer.

Comment: https://www.jpost.com/health-science/covid-just-006-percent-israelis-sick-after-two-shots-no-one-serious-study-657871 is the one report I've seen reported on... hopefully other data is available too though indeed

Comment: Well, there is some data now, even from the US: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/a/26282/10980